# Cómo puedo crear mi usuario con django

Tags: django, django-models

Estoy creando un registro de usuario en django (no quiero utilizar el que trae django por defecto) y no consigo que mi formulario cree un usuario con los datos del formulario.

mi **forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class SignInForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    repeat_password = forms.CharField(label='Repeat Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

mi **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import bcrypt
import hashlib
import sha3

class Usuario(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12, help_text="The name must be between 2 and 12 characters")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, unique=True, help_text="The email must be between 5 and 30 characters")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ip = models.CharField(default="",max_length=15)
    last_login = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    wallets = models.CharField(default="",max_length=150)
    coins = models.CharField(default="", max_length=150)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    delete_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=9)
    two_factors_auth = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    two_factors_auth_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=12)
    fingerprint = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def create(self, email, password, ip, fingerprint):
        self.name = email.split("@")[0]
        self.email = email
        self.password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
        #compare hashed: bcrypt.hashpw(input, self.password) == self.password:
        self.ip = str([ip])
        self.avatar = "new"
        self.fingerprint = sha3.sha3_224(str(fingerprint).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        self.save()
```

mi **views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from home.forms import *
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from home.models import Usuario

class homePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['contact_form'] = ContactForm(prefix='contact')
    context['login_form'] = LogInForm(prefix='login')
    context['signIn_form'] = SignInForm(prefix='signin')
    return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    contact_name = request.POST.get('contact-name')
    contact_email = request.POST.get('contact-email')
    contact_subject = request.POST.get('contact-subject')
    contact_message = request.POST.get('contact-message')
    login_email = request.POST.get('login-email')
    login_password = request.POST.get('login-password')
    signin_email = request.POST.get('signin-email')
    signin_password = request.POST.get('signin-password') 
    signin_repeat_password = request.POST.get('signin-repeat_password')
    if request.method == "POST": 
        if 'SignInButton' in request.POST:
                if signin_email and signin_password and signin_repeat_password and signin_password == signin_repeat_password:
                    form = SignInForm(request.POST, prefix='signin')
                    print(form)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        user = form.save(commit=False)
                        fingerprint = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT')+request.META.get('COMPUTERNAME')+request.META.get('OS')
                        user.create(self,signin_email, signin_password, request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR'), fingerprint)
                        # usuario.save(request.'signin-email')
                    #Logica para registrar al usuario usuario y redirigir a la plataforma request.
                    # create(self, email, password, ip, fingerprint)
                    return redirect('home') #aqui va la redireccion a la plataforma
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Any error ocurred.')
        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html')
```

por último, mi formulario

```
<!-- Modal Sign In-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="SignInModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="SignInModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="logInModalLongTitle">Sign In</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <p> {{ signIn_form.email.label }} </p>
                    {% render_field signIn_form.email class+="form-control" %}
                    {{ signIn_form.email.errors }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <p> {{ signIn_form.password.label }} </p>
                    {% render_field signIn_form.password class+="form-control" id="signin_password"%}
                    {{ signIn_form.password.errors }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <p> {{ signIn_form.repeat_password.label }} </p>
                    {% render_field signIn_form.repeat_password class+="form-control" id="signin_repeat_password" %}
                    {{ signIn_form.repeat_password.errors }}
                  </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" /> I have read and agree to the Terms of use</p>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" name="SignInButton" class="btn btn-primary" id ="SignInButton" hidden>Continue</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button name="validateButton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="validateSignIn()">Continue</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

El problema creo que está en views, pero no estoy muy seguro.
¿Alguna idea?

Comment: que te da como resultado: print(form)

Comment: Podrias basarte como lo hacen en la documentacion: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects

Comment: @Tegito123 el print devuelve: <tr><th><label for="id_signin-email">Email:</label></th><td><input type="email" name="signin-email" value="and@gmail.com" required id="id_signin-email" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_signin-password">Password:</label></th><td><input type="password" name="signin-password" required id="id_signin-password" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_signin-repeat_password">Repeat Password:</label></th><td><input type="password" name="signin-repeat_password" required id="id_signin-repeat_password" /></td></tr>

Comment: y has probado como te indique en el link

Comment: @Tegito123 Pues el problema es que en la documentación llaman al método save() pero en mis modelos tengo más datos que los que pido en el formulario, y no se muy bien cómo gestionar eso.

Comment: @Tegito123 he pensado en hacer esto: user = Usuario()
                        user.name = email.split("@")[0]
                        user.email = email
                        user.password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
                        #compare hashed: bcrypt.hashpw(input, self.password) == self.password:
                        user.ip = str([ip])
                        user.avatar = "new"
                        user.fingerprint = sha3.sha3_224(str(fingerprint).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
                        user.save()

Comment: if signin_email and signin_password and signin_repeat_password and signin_password == signin_repeat_password:........en esta linea tienes tambien problemas... estas comparando... tu email(signin_email) con tus passsword... lo cual nunca sucedera

Comment: debes hacer la pregunta solo para tu signin_password y signin_repeat_password, mas no con el email

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79388/discussion-between-antoni-cobos-and-tegito123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente para crearlo podrias usar como menciona la documentacion oficial

[Creando Objetos](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects)

```
   #datos del post 
   contact_name = request.POST.get('contact-name')
    contact_email = request.POST.get('contact-email')
usuario = Usuario(
  name=contact_name,
  email = contact_email
  ....
  ....
)
usuario.save()
```

Ahora de esta forma solo guarda directamente el usuario, no validas o verificas su existe o no en tu BD, te sugiero usar un try ..except: ejemplo:

```
try:
 usuario = Usuario.objects.get(name=contact_name, email=contact_email) 
 ....
 ...
 si exist este user le das la opcion para actualizar los datos, o actualizas directamente.
except Usuario.DoesNotExist :
 #en caso de no existir el usuario lo creas
 usuario = Usuario(
  name=contact_name,
  email = contact_email
  ....
  ....
)
usuario.save()
```

Espero te sirva y suerte !!

Comment: Muchas gracias!